# How to export model as alembic file with texture material (color)?

Tags: animation, materials, geometry-nodes, color, alembic

I have created a 3d model with animations. But when I export it as an alembic file, the color/texture I have added goes away. I made the model using geometry nodes. There are a total of three objects in the collection which i then made into the figure below using gn. Each instance has animation.[image] What do I do?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures